# Can we monitor a database table read operation row-wise?

Tags: sql-server, database, monitoring

I want to monitor, using a "read operation" on my one table in my database on SQL Server 2008.

So I want to know which row fetched at what time in that table.

It's not possible for me to do logging in my application.

Comment: What constitutes a "read"? Do you mean you want to log whenever any `SELECT` operation results in data being read from a row? What if the row is initially included in a subquery but excluded in an outer-query? What about non-SELECT operations that still result in a read (e.g. `UPDATE` or `MERGE`)? What about page-level database operations that expose row-level data or backup operations?

Comment: Hi Dai, yes I mean "select" query. for background, this is my standard table, I won't operate any update, Merge, delete, edit command there. and exclusion never happens in my particular case for the subquery. so I want all select query run on this table

Comment: do you want to monitor adhoc TSQL only, or stored proc access to the table as well?

Comment: Hi I need access of Tsql as well as stored proc also

Comment: OP's Comment below: "Indexing is not done on that database." - erm, what? You have bigger problems....

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct, you want to know every time your data were "displayed" to the end user? You can use a stored procedure to run your select statement (get data), but as a second statement run an insert into a log table with a timestamp and whatever information you are interested in.

```
CREATE PROC get_data
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO log_table(timestamp,info1,info2)
    VALUES (GETDATE(), info1, info2)

    SELECT col1,col2
    FROM my_data

END
GO
```

Something like this.

Comment: Hi Ruslan, I am working on almost 15 year old very big software.  I even don't know from how many places this software run select query. so I need a type of outside log system on this table. the above solution won't work for me.

Comment: I see, then you can probably get some kind of idea by looking at the index stats (hopefully you got some clustered ones) and resetting them(or collecting them) every so often to get an idea [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Indexing is not done on that database. Yes it's silly but true in my case.

Comment: You can use profiler to trace it but I would not recommend to do it in production because it's going to be heavy for the server.